# DllNotFoundException: hid.dll C# Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, dll

I am connecting a RFIDReader using USB and trying to communicate with it. It works well on windows. But this program should run on my raspberry pi whose operating system is raspbian and it tells me that a dll called hid.dll cannot be found when the program tried using the API of the RFIDReader. I guess its because the hid.dll is specific to windows. Since Linux doesn't have hid.dll, is there anything I can do to solve the problem to still get my program run on Linux? Is there anything similar to Hid.dll in linux?

My code dealing with the reader is as follows. When it executes the method InitReader() the problem will appear. Hope there's anyone can help me, thanks a lot!

```
using SkyeTek.Devices;
using SkyeTek.Tags;
using SkyeTek.STPv3;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace RFIDReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// this class represents the RFID reader, used to set the reader, send commond to the reader and ask response from the reader
    /// </summary>
    public class RFIDReader : EventArgs
    {
        public Device rfidReader { get; set; }
        public String tagID;
        public String buffer;
        public static int count;
        Thread timer; //the thread responsible for counting the timeout
        public static bool tagRead = false; // determine if a person can pay for a product when a tag is detected
        public event EventHandler<RFIDReader> TagDetected; //Tag detected event, raised once a tag is detected by the reader

        /// <summary>
        /// initiate the reader, set it as auto scanning tags
        /// </summary>
        public void InitReader()
        {
            if (FindLinkedDevices())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RFIDReader: Opening device:  " + rfidReader.ToString());
                rfidReader.Open();
                AutoScanTags();
                rfidReader.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// scanning tags automatically
        /// </summary>
        public void AutoScanTags()
        {
            STPv3Request request;
            STPv3Response response;
            SkyeTek.Tags.Tag tag = new SkyeTek.Tags.Tag();
            tag.Type = TagType.AUTO_DETECT;

            // Build the SelectTag request
            request = new STPv3Request();
            request.Command = STPv3Commands.SELECT_TAG;
            request.Tag = tag;

            //set the reader's flag as loop mode and inventory mode. So The reader reads all the tags in the field and then continuously
            //scans for any tags that enter the field and reports back their tag IDs.
            request.Loop = true;
            request.Inventory = true;

            // Issue the request to the output device
            while (true)
            {
                request.Issue(rfidReader);
                response = request.GetResponse();

                if (response.ResponseCode == STPv3ResponseCode.SELECT_TAG_PASS)
                {
                    //paymentValid = false;
                    buffer = BitConverter.ToString(response.TID);
                    if (buffer.Length > 0 && !buffer.Equals(tagID)) //if the tagID is a new ID, rasie tagdetected event, send data to RFIDData instance and start the timer
                    {
                        if (timer != null && timer.IsAlive)
                        {
                            timer.Abort();
                        }
                        tagID = buffer;
                        OnTagDetected(tagID);
                        timer = new Thread(Timing);
                        timer.Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (buffer.Length > 0 && count >= 5) // if the tagID is not a new ID, check the timeout. If time is over, rasie tagdetected event, send data to RFIDData instance and start the timer
                        {
                            tagID = buffer;
                            OnTagDetected(tagID);
                            timer = new Thread(Timing);
                            timer.Start();
                        }
                        /*else
                        {
                            if(buffer.Length >0 && count >= 3 && request.GetResponse() != null)
                            {
                                paymentValid = true;
                            }
                        }*/
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find the readers connected to the computer
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool FindLinkedDevices()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RFIDReader: Enumerating linked devices");
            Device[] LinkedDevices = USBDeviceFactory.Enumerate();
            //Identify the RFID reader
            if (LinkedDevices.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RFIDReader: No USB devices found");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Device i in LinkedDevices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RFIDReader: USB devices found ---> " + i.ToString());
                    if (i.ToString().Equals("SkyeTek.Devices.USBDevice"))
                    {
                        rfidReader = i;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rasie an tagDetected event once the reader detects a tag
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="TID"></param>
        protected virtual void OnTagDetected(String TID)
        {
            if (TagDetected != null)
            {
                TagDetected(this, new RFIDReader() { tagID = TID });
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// timing method running on the timer thread
        /// </summary>
        public void Timing()
        {
            for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming your device and its API are from "SkyeTek" then they have seemingly provided you with a Windows only API, there is no quick fix to make it work on other operating systems.  You will need to look/contact them to see if they provide a Linux compatible API.

Comment: They only provide C API for Linux, not .Net API. Is the C API could be any solution?